# Geometry. Showing that this is a pre-geodesic.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

There is a surface $$p(u,v)=(\rm sech \,v \cos{u},\rm sech\,v \sin{u},v-\rm tanh\,v) (v>0)$$

On the surface, there is a curve $$\hat r(t) =p \circ r(t)\,\,,\,\, r(t)=(u(t),v(t))$$

And $$u(t)^2+{\rm cosh}^2v(t)=a^2$$ ($a$ is a constant greater than 1)

In this situation, I want to show that $\hat r$ is a pre-geodesic.

I learned that to show it is a pre-geodesic, I have to show that det(${d\hat r \over dt}, {d^2\hat r \over dt^2}, \nu$) is zero.

I tried but it was very complicated calculation..Is there anyone who can help me?

Thanks for reading